# can userid field replace the username field to assemble a JID when use openfire?

Tags: database, xmpp, openfire

I have integrated the content of 'ofproperty' table of openfire to some table of custom database. by default the openfire use username to asssemble JID as a sign every single user.
After setting the system properties of openfire(some sql statements), it will make the 'ofuser'table in openfire point to 'users' table of the business database.
**what i am not sure is that whether openfire inner mechanism only identify the username or not**?

because my entire instant message is close to done, and now i am asked to try userid to replace username, the change will concern lots of other business logic in my project. I don't want to see the circumstance that every change is done,but openfire mechanism does not accept it.

**if i use userid to replace username to assemble the jid, and correspondingly change the setting properties of openfire,  will it still work？**

Hope some experienced people give me some advice..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think this will not work if openfire is using DefaultAuthProvider.java for user authentication. Because DefaultAuthProvider.java uses a static sql string

```
private static final String LOAD_PASSWORD =
        "SELECT plainPassword,encryptedPassword FROM ofUser WHERE username=?";
```

so if you change in your system properties that won't work. You can do one of the following two things

1. Change the LOAD_PASSWORD string inside DefaultAuthProvider.java (inside source code) accoring to your need and then compile it and Enjoy :)
2. Write you own AuthProvider by implementing AuthProvider Interface

I think first one is little easier

Comment: thank you @Haider Ali,i fixed this problem, as you said,if the DefaultAuthProvider.java is used, it will not work. but we can replace   it with JDBCAuthProvider.java. but if then we just change all the username to userid in all sql String of the property setting,it still will not work,because most condition the userid field's type is integer in our business database while openfire seem s only accept Character type. So what we need to do is to replace username with userid::text in all above sql.., as long as we can use userid login onto openfire management ,then we make it.